# ¿Como saber con Javascript si alguien salio de mi web?

Tags: javascript

En mi web envío a los usuarios en cierta parte a WhatsApp con:

```
window.open("whatsapp://send?text=Hola!","_self");
```

mediante un botón, pero quiero detectar cuando esa persona sale específicamente, ya que cuando se intenta hacer esto se pregunta al usuario si quiere "abrir o no" WhatsApp, entonces si da click en "No" o en "Si" quiero saberlo para poder seguir manejando las siguientes funcionalidades.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber obtenido una solución, use este método:

```
$(window).on('blur', ()=>{ //código// });
```

Es un poco inestable, porque se ejecuta mas veces de las que debería, pero con el click del botón puedo manejar la cantidad de veces que la persona deja la web.

Comment: En la documentación oficial acerca de [Visibility Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) hay una nota que indica que tanto **onblur** como **onfocus** no dan cuenta efectiva del cierre o abandono de la ventana. Tu solución es incorrecta. Puede parecer que funciona pero te va a dar sorpresas.